# Using zlib and cPickle to compress/decompress a dictionary to files

Tags: python, zlib, pickle

I am using python to write to a file a zlib compressed and cPickled dictionary. It appears to work, however, I cannot figure out how to read the file back in.

I'm including the following code which includes several of the things I've tried (and the associated error messages). I'm getting nowhere.

```
import sys
import cPickle as pickle
import zlib

testDict = { 'entry1':1.0, 'entry2':2.0 }

with open('test.gz', 'wb') as fp:
  fp.write(zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(testDict, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL),9))

attempt = 0

try:
  attempt += 1
  with open('test.gz', 'rb') as fp:
    step1 = zlib.decompress(fp)
    successDict = pickle.load(step1)
except Exception, e:
  print "Failed attempt:", attempt, e

try:
  attempt += 1
  with open('test.gz', 'rb').read() as fp:
    step1 = zlib.decompress(fp)
    successDict = pickle.load(step1)
except Exception, e:
  print "Failed attempt:", attempt, e

try:
  attempt += 1
  with open('test.gz', 'rb') as fp:
    step1 = zlib.decompress(fp.read())
    successDict = pickle.load(step1)
except Exception, e:
  print "Failed attempt:", attempt, e

try:
  attempt += 1
  with open('test.gz', 'rb') as fp:
    d = zlib.decompressobj()
    step1 = fp.read()
    step2 = d.decompress(step1)
    step3 = pickle.load(step2)
except Exception ,e:
  print "Failed attempt:", attempt, e

try:
  attempt += 1
  with open('test.gz', 'rb') as fp:
    d = zlib.decompressobj()
    step1 = fp.read()
    step2 = d.decompress(step1)
    step3 = pickle.load(step2)
except Exception ,e:
  print "Failed attempt:", attempt, e
```

I get the following errors:

```
Failed attempt: 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not file
Failed attempt: 2 __exit__
Failed attempt: 3 argument must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes
Failed attempt: 4 argument must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes
Failed attempt: 5 argument must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes
```

Hopefully this is just some obvious (to someone else) fix that I am just missing. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The errors you are getting on attempts 3-5 are because you're using `pickle.load` instead of `pickle.loads`. The former expects a file-like object, rather than the byte string you're getting from the decompression calls.

This will work:

```
with open('test.gz', 'rb') as fp:
    data = zlib.decompress(fp.read())
    successDict = pickle.loads(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

According to pickle manual you need to use `pickle.load*s*` http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/node317.html (remove the '*' obviously)